# Adding a vertical line at the right end of the horizontal line in \frac

Tags: fractions

I'd like to use a mathematical notation that looks like a fraction \frac{A}{B}, with an additional vertical line that extends from the right end of the horizontal line down towards the base line of the denominator. Is there an easy way to achieve this in such a way that it scales correctly in different settings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I measure the fraction in the current style, via `\mathpalette`. Then I add a `\vrule` that's as high as the math axis (`\fontdimen22` of the current font in family 2) plus half of the default rule thickness (`\fontdime8` of the current font in family 3), as deep as the fraction and with width the default rule thickness.

Some negative space is needed, which is `-\nulldelimiterspace`, that I add back after the construction.

In order to leave some room, I added thin spaces on either side in the denominator.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % comment out for pdflatex

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\funnyfrac}[2]{{\mathpalette\funny@frac{{#1}{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\funny@frac}[2]{\funny@@frac#1#2}% trick for passing three args to \mathpalette
\newcommand{\funny@@frac}[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\frac{#2}{\,#3\,}$}%
  \usebox\z@
  \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  \funny@fractionrule{#1}%
  \kern\nulldelimiterspace
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\math@param}[3]{%
  \fontdimen#3
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont#2
  \else\ifx#1\textstyle\textfont#2
  \else\ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont#2
  \else\scriptscriptfont#2 \fi\fi\fi
}
\@ifpackageloaded{unicode-math}{%
  \usepackage{ifluatex}
  \ifluatex
    \newcommand{\funny@fractionrule}[1]{%
      \vrule height \dimexpr\Umathaxis#1+0.5\Umathfractionrule#1\relax
             depth \dp\z@
             width \Umathfractionrule#1\relax
    }
  \else
    \usepackage{xfp}
    \newcommand{\funny@fractionrule}[1]{%
      \sbox\tw@{$\textstyle x$}\sbox\@tempboxa{$#1x$}%
      \vrule height \fpeval{\ht\@tempboxa/\ht\tw@}%
                    \dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2+0.5\fontdimen8\textfont3\relax
             depth \dp\z@
             width \fpeval{\ht\@tempboxa/\ht\tw@}\fontdimen8\textfont3
    }
  \fi
}{% no unicode-math
  \newcommand{\funny@fractionrule}[1]{%
    \vrule height \dimexpr\math@param{#1}{2}{22}+0.5\math@param{#1}{3}{8}\relax
           depth \dp\z@
           width \math@param{#1}{3}{8} % default rule width
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle\funnyfrac{a}{b}$
$\textstyle\funnyfrac{a}{b}$
$\scriptstyle\funnyfrac{a}{b}$
$\scriptscriptstyle\funnyfrac{a}{b}$
$\displaystyle\funnyfrac{a}{\dfrac{1}{2}}$
$\funnyfrac{a+b}{c}+\funnyfrac{a}{b+c}$

\end{document}
```

[image: zzz]

Comment: Thanks, this is also very nice! When using unicode-math and LuaLaTeX it gives unwanted results in subscripts (as does frougon's solution). But that's not such a big problem, since I doubt I'll use it in subscripts.

Comment: @Michael I added the code for LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Michael Now the code is for all three engines; `xfp` is needed for `xelatex`.

Comment: @egreg Pfiouuuuu, impressive. I see you drastically changed the horizontal spacing in recent edits. I need to wrap the `\usepackage{unicode-math}` inside `\ifluatex ... \fi` in order to compile your code with pdfTeX (maybe this is incorrect for XeTeX, though). The error message is: `unicode-math Error: Cannot be run with pdfLaTeX!
(unicode-math)                Use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX instead`.

Comment: @frougon The `\providecommand` does something only if `unicode-math` is not loaded and the code is run through `pdflatex`. Just comment out `\usepackage{unicode-math}`.

Comment: @egreg Hmm, it seems to me it's the `\usepackage{unicode-math}` that fails with `pdfTeX`. I do see the error, and it disappears if I comment out this `\usepackage{unicode-math}` (TL 2019 from up-to-date Debian unstable).

Comment: @frougon Of course: you can't have `\usepackage{unicode-math}` if you run `pdflatex`. I added a comment for that.

Comment: @frougon Now the code requires packages only if `unicode-math` is loaded.

Answer (score 6):

The code below should get you the correct depth for the rule.

In the first version, I assumed a fraction rule width equal to 0.4pt (default rule width). Thanks to [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499972/73317), I replaced this 0.4pt with a macro that expands to the `\fontdimen8` of the appropriate math font (`\textfont3`, `\scriptfont3` or `\scriptscriptfont3`, depending on the current math style).

The syntax is very easy: just use `\strange` or `\strangeii` instead of `\frac`.

Note: I added the `\Bigg` delimiters not because they look nice, but in order to show that the vertical rule is as deep as the fraction denominator, not as deep as the whole formula—which would be the case if one were to remove the outer set of braces in the replacement texts of `\strange` and `\strangeii` (these braces create a *subformula* that is as high and as deep as the fraction).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter

% Small amount of expl3 code for the DRY principle
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__michael_mathchoice:nnnn #1#2#3#4
  { \mathchoice {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4} }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__michael_mathchoice:nnnn { oooo }

% Expand to a \fontdimen parameter of a math font
%
% #1: 'text', 'script' or 'scriptscript' (for \textfont, \scriptfont or
%     \scriptscriptfont, respectively)
% #2: font family (0-16)
% #3: number of the font parameter (cf. TeXbook p. 447)
\cs_new:Npn \__michael_math_param:nnn #1#2#3
  { \fontdimen #3 \use:c { #1font } #2 }

% Default rule width \__michael_math_param:nnn {#1} {3} {8} based on a hint
% from egreg's answer (<https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499972/73317>).
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__michael_small_rule:n #1
  {
    \vrule
      width  \dim_eval:n { \__michael_math_param:nnn {#1} {3} {8} }
      height \dim_eval:n { \__michael_math_param:nnn {#1} {2} {22} +
                           0.5\__michael_math_param:nnn {#1} {3} {8} }
    \relax
  }

% Generate the vertical rule to be used on the right of the fraction
% in the appropriate style.
\NewDocumentCommand \michaelsmallrule { }
  {
    \__michael_mathchoice:oooo
      { \__michael_small_rule:n { text } }
      { \__michael_small_rule:n { text } }
      { \__michael_small_rule:n { script } }
      { \__michael_small_rule:n { scriptscript } }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*{\strangeii}[2]{% No need for the % here: we are in math mode
  { \frac{#1}{#2} \michaelsmallrule }
}

% See <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233033/73317> and TeXbook p. 150
\newcommand*{\strange}[2]{% with correction for horizontal space
  { \frac{#1}{#2} \kern-\nulldelimiterspace \michaelsmallrule }
}

\newcommand*{\mytest}[1]{%
  \par
  In text style: $\Biggl(2 + #1{x+1}{(2y-8)^2} \Biggr)$; in subscripts and
  subsubscripts:
  $\Gamma_{ #1{a+1}{1+#1{x}{y}^{#1{\alpha}{\beta}}} }$; finally, in a display formula:
  \[ \Biggl( 2 + #1{x+1}{(2y-8)^2} \Biggr). \]
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section*{With \texttt{\string\strange}}

\mytest{\strange}

\section*{With \texttt{\string\strangeii}}

\mytest{\strangeii}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Zoom on the first expression that shows `\strange` in `\scriptstyle` and in `\scriptscriptstyle`:

[image: Zoomed in]

## For fun

It is possible to push the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) a bit further in the `expl3` code. I didn't do it above, because I think it makes the code significantly harder to read; but in case you are interested, here you are:

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__michael_small_rule_aux:n #1
  { \__michael_mathchoice:oooo #1 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__michael_small_rule_aux:n { V }

% Generate the little vertical rule from middle to top of the fraction rule
% in the appropriate style.
\NewDocumentCommand \michaelsmallrule { }
  {
    % Prepare the argument list for the four styles; store it in \l_tmpa_tl.
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \clist_map_inline:nn { text, text, script, scriptscript }
      {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { { \__michael_small_rule:n {##1} } }
      }

    % Expand \l_tmpa_tl to construct the four arguments (they correspond to
    % the arguments of \mathchoice, except that one expansion step will be
    % done in each argument before it is fed to \matchoice)
    \__michael_small_rule_aux:V \l_tmpa_tl
  }
```

This can replace the definition of `\michaelsmallrule` in the complete code sample given above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This looks good. I haven't been able to get your last edit working, but with the previous edit using LuaLaTeX and unicode-math, the vertical line extended above the horizontal line in subscript style. Any idea why, or how to fix it? Unfortunately I would need a lot more background to understand what your code does.

Comment: The [last edit so far](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/499946/8) is only a minor text change, what do you mean? Can you post minimal code (e.g., on pastebin.com, etc.)? The code I posted works fine with LuaTeX here (`lualuatex` executable). Do you mean the “For fun” section, maybe?

Comment: Here is a MWE to illustrate the problem with LuaLaTeX and unicode-math. It does not yet use the for fun edit. https://pastebin.com/UEj2J3Mh

Comment: But it's not such a big problem, since I doubt that I'll use the notation in subscripts, so thanks again for the effort!

Comment: Thanks for the example. So, with `unicode-math`, `\fontdimen22` of the appropriate math font doesn't seem to give the axis height contrary to what the TeXbook p. 447 seems to imply (also [Heiko Oberdiek's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250151/73317)). I wonder if it is an `unicode-math` bug... In case you didn't notice, I found that the `1.2pt` is simply `\nulldelimiterspace` (and always the same unless you change it yourself). The “For fun” section is just a different programming style (smarter but less readable!), the behavior will be exactly the same.

Comment: Also, the fraction rules appear to be thinner in `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle` than in `\textstyle` when `unicode-math` is used; this doesn't happen with the default rendering (non-`unicode-math`). Interesting...

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[ \frac{A }{B\smash{\rule{0.4pt}{2.2ex}}} \quad\frac{A}{B}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks! Unfortunately, in inline math mode the vertical bar extends above the horizontal one. Similarly in subscript style. (I'm using LuaLaTeX with unicode-math)

Comment: The vertical line height  a problem of trial and error. I guess the `ex` unit is the global ex of the document, not of the fraction. You could use `\mathpalette` to ensure it works also in indices, subindices, &c.

Answer (score 3):

My proposal is to change the `holtpolt.sty` and adapt for the fraction without left vertical bar, as the image in attachment:

The image is:

[image]

and the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\holter}[2]{\begin{array}{c}\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#2}\end{array}}
\begin{document}
$\holter{A}{B}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not seem to scale like \frac to inline math or subscript style.

Comment: @Michael It is predefinite symbol of the list symbols-a4.pdf. See Table 268: holtpolt Non-commutative Division Symbols. http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Only for fun.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\newcommand{\mytikzmark}[2]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,inner sep=-1pt,outer sep=0pt,baseline,anchor=base] 
    \node (#1) {\ensuremath{#2}};}

\begin{document}

\[ q 
  = \mytikzmark{n}{\dfrac{{Q_l}}{2}} 
  \]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \draw (n.-10)  --++(-90:0.35);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]